# In SSAS Parent-Child-Hierarchy how to use MembersWithDataCaption

Tags: ssas, dimension

I have a parent-child-hierarchy with `MemberWithData=NonLeadDataVisible`. I tried different values for `MembersWithDataCaption`, but I always get name of datamember equal to name of inner node. I am using SSAS 12.0.5538.0.

Questions:

- Where to set `MemberWithDataCaption`, Parent or Key?
- `MemberWithDataCaption` is a formatstring, how does it work? For
  simplicity I set the value "parent" without effect (after deploy and 
  process).
- What are the conditions for `MemberWithDataCaption` to actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was I used a **translation** (german) and left the translation for `MemberWithDataCaption` empty. An other pitfall is a formatstring without a '*' does not work.

Answers:

- Set `MemberWithDataCaption` of the Parent and any translations
- In the formatstring the first star is replaced with the original
  name, succeeding star will not be replaced.

Examples:

```
formatstring   original name   resulting caption
------------------------------------------------
constant       Charly          Charly
* (dm)         Charly          Charly (dm)
(*) *          Charly          (Charly) *
```

- The conditions are:

  - Set `MemberWithData`=`NonLeafDataVisible`
  - Use a Formatstring containing a '*'
  - If you use translations, provide a translated formatstring